# Error using sparse index into matrix is too large

Tags: matlab, indexing, sparse-matrix

I ve got a huge adjacency matrix in a sparse representation. I ve got 70.000 and 300.000 edges and the structure of adjacency file is a Nx3 matrix with the first two columns to be the connected nodes the the third column to be the weight. I am trying to read from matlab. Firstly I import the file, and secondly I am trying to create the sparse matrix with spconvert:

```
adj1 = spconvert(gr);
```

However I am receiving the following error message:

```
??? Error using ==> sparse
Index into matrix is too large.
Error in ==> spconvert at 53
   S = sparse(D(:,1),D(:,2),D(:,3));
```

The biggest value of the matrix is 2.537020525000000e+09 and correspond to a node. Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: `spconvert` does not work with a 3D matrix (you have a NxNx3 matrix right?). I am a bit confused whether you have a Nx3 matrix (thus TWO dimensions), or you have a 3D matrix with NxNxN values, could you maybe clarify that? Either way, `spconvert` needs three rows, with the first two rows defining connected nodes and the third giving the connection weight.

Comment: You are right, I edit my question instead of dimension I mean columns. I ve got a nx3 matrix. The first two cols are stand for connected nodes and the third for connection weight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of `sparse` it tells you that:

> Note:   If any value in i or j is larger than 2^31-1 for 32-bit platforms, or 2^48-1 on 64-bit platforms, then the sparse matrix cannot be constructed.

This corresponds to `2.15 e^09` for the maximum biggest value on a 32-bit platform and therefore that is giving you the error message since your biggest value is larger than this. As a solution I propose rescaling your weight values, for instance with log.

Comment: Basically I transform the node indexes from 1-65098 so as not to have probs. Thanks for the time Fraukje.

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help. Good luck!